# How to create a global variable to manipulate outside of an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have an image I called from a JSON file

```
success: function(data) {   
    console.log(data.items[0].thumbnailImage);
```

Can someone tell me how to turn this thumbnail into a global variable that I can use to display within html img tags?

I just want to have more control over the JSON data but I don't know how to manipulate it outside of the ajax call

I realize I have alot to learn here but an example would really help.

Thanks

> Here is an example I found:
>
> (function($) {
>
> var url = 'http://www.jquery4u.com/scripts/jquery4u-sites.json?callback=?';
>
> $.ajax({
>
> type: 'GET',
>    url: url,
>    async: false,
>    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
>    contentType: "application/json",
>    dataType: 'jsonp',
>    success: function(json) {
>         console.dir(json.sites);
>      },
>      error: function(e) {
>         console.log(e.message);
>      }
>   });
>
> })(jQuery);
>
> The end of this example states that : "The output should be the JSON as an object which we can then use the data for whatever we want without restrictions."
>
> Can you give me some examples of how to use the data for whatever I want without restrictions given the thumbnailimage I have available from my external JSON file I called in the earlier example?
>
> Really all I want to do is be able to take the image and manipulate/display the image in html/css.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you want to be able to do. This question sounds  bit like how to access ajax response outside of the success callback .. which is going down the wrong road

Comment: save the images in some folder of your server and try to get the path of the images and set the path to the src attributes of the img tags that you want to.

Answer (score 1):

You really can't. AJAX is asynchronous - once you make that `XMLHttpRequest` the function execution is done outside the context in which it is called. Asynchronous functions *need* callbacks in order to complete, the rest of the linear code that executed before and after the AJAX call has nothing to do with it anymore. Any answer that says you can just assign a global variable inside the (asynchronous) success handler and use it without also calling the function that uses that variable *from* the success handler is straight up wrong.

This asynchronous callback event loop is the whole basis of node.js. There is no getting around it.

Comment: This is right, but he didn't asked how to declare a global variable inside of the AJAX call, just how to store the result into a global variable.

Comment: But there is no conceivable point to that unless the function using the global variable is called from the callback too.

Comment: Okay, good point.
But if he uses the picture only once, he should directly create the image. Else he MUST store it in a variable outside the AJAX call, no?

Answer (score 0):

First way would be to define the variable gloabally, then do the AJAX-call and then assign the response to the variable.

Another solution would be to set the image directly. What format does your response have? Maybe you need to do this:

```
img.src = data.items[0].thumbnailImage;
```

Comment: How do I apply this to html? I want to be able to pick and choose which thumbnail item I want to display on the web browser. For example I would like to display data.item[0].thumbnailimage and data.item[3].thumbnailimage on the screen. How do I do this? the only way I have found to do this is by using this....success: function(data) { 
  var image = document.querySelector('img');
  image.setAttribute ('src', data.items[8].thumbnailImage);
  console.log(data.items[0].thumbnailImage);

Answer (score -1):

This is a vague question, and thus my answer is fairly vague.

Declare whatever you want to store your return in outside of the AJAX call, like an array of images. Then in the success handle of the AJAX, add it to that data store and handle it however makes sense for you, (eg append it, update current images, etc.)

```
var myImages = [];

function addNewImage(newImage){
 myImages.push(newImage);
 //do whatever you want with new image here

}

$.get('some/url').success(
function(newImage){
 addNewImage(newImage);
})
```